# Umbraco 4.9.1 - Error loading macro engine script

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am using Umbraco since a year now and I have some problems with the MacroEngineCore. Sometimes, the macro engine crash and I don't really know why but I manage to extract the error below.

I am using Razor and the error only comes sometimes and I cannot really find a reason about it.
I tried to make a home fix but still didn't work in the RazorMacroEngine.cs.

Now I am completely stuck and I am looking forward your answers.

Thanks you in advance,

Lenny

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url)   at ASP._Page_macroScripts_Redirect_cshtml.Execute() "in file here":line 35   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext; TextWriter writer; WebPageRenderingBase startPage)   at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro; INode currentPage)

Comment: Can you elaborate a littlebit more?  I mean, is this problem poping up of all macro's?  Did you patched the core yourself?  Maybe supply code from your macro.  Have you tried with adding ?umbdebugshowtrace=true  to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did patch the core my self and the bug is less frequent but still often anyway.
Not all the macro crashes some of them do more than others, and the weird part is that they don't crash all the time.

Here is one of the macro that crash some times (The others are kind of big)

> @{
>       var homeNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf("HomeLanguage");
>       var modules = homeNode.Descendants("Modules").First();
>       var socialnetworks = modules.Descendants("SocialNetworks").First();
>       int i = 0;
>   }
>       @foreach (var socNet in socialnetworks.ChildrenAsList)
>       {
>           //Get link with @socNet.GetPropertyValue("link")
>           //Display it with HTML.
>       }

I just modified the file RazorMacroEngine.cs in the RazorCore (function "ExecuteRazor").
I added a loop in case of a crash and I stop it after 5 tries and added a Sleep of 100ms in case it bugs so I wait to release some resources.

Did it ever happened to anybody?